# Creating a nuget package that has a projectreference to another package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am working on developing a NuGet package named `Foo`, which has a project dependency on another package named `Foo.Models`. The goal is to allow clients to install the `Foo.Models` package separately in a different assembly, providing flexibility to utilize the models without inheriting the dependencies of the main `Foo` package.

An excellent example of this approach is observed in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`. Upon examining the Microsoft source code, it appears they use `ProjectReference` instead of `PackageReference`. This is ideal to avoid confusion that might arise with `PackageReference`, because the source code in the repository isn't the code that's actually guaranteed to be used.

I am seeking guidance on how to configure and publish such a package, maintaining a project dependency on my own package (`Foo.Models`) while utilizing `ProjectReference`. I'm particularly interested in understanding how Microsoft achieves this in their source code.

Comment: AFAIK this is standard functionality. When you will pack the project it will consider all `ProjectReference` as package dependencies.

Comment: @GuruStron but how does that work when I only push package `Foo`? Will it also create a package for `Foo.Models` and push the changes to NuGet as well?

Comment: It will not, you need to publish both. No, it will not automatically publish the dependency one.

Comment: So how does the Foo package know that it needs to grab Foo.Models from NuGet? If I look at the Microsoft example I mention, it has a version dependency on Abstractions. How can that work if I only use ProjectReference?

Comment: _"So how does the Foo package know that it needs to grab Foo.Models from NuGet?"_ - because it treats `ProjectReference` as a dependency. _"How can that work if I only use ProjectReference?"_ - to build a project with a dependency you need that project dependency to be built too, i.e. you will have info about project's version too.